# Windows batch file loop to print a file multiple times

Tags: batch-file, printing

I print a `.prn` file with `cmd` using command

```
COPY test.PRN \\Desktop\Xerox_WorkCentre_5024
```

This works fine.

If I wish to print the same file twice, I use this command:

```
COPY test.PRN \\Desktop\Xerox_WorkCentre_5024
timeout 300 /NOBREAK**
COPY test.PRN \\Desktop\Xerox_WorkCentre_5024
```

This also works fine, printing the same file twice after a delay of 300 Seconds.

Now, in a Batch file, how a For Loop I should use if I want to print the same file 25 times with same time delay interval in between?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FOR /L`

In `FOR /?`

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]

    The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
    So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
    generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
```

If you want to do

```
COPY test.PRN \\Desktop\Xerox_WorkCentre_5024
timeout 300 /NOBREAK
```

25 times, in a batch-file you could do this:

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%I in (1,1,25) do (
  COPY test.PRN \\Desktop\Xerox_WorkCentre_5024
  timeout 300 /NOBREAK
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are always many ways to skin a cat.

using a `for /L` loop in a batch file. (Note, if you want to use this same line from `cmd` you need to use `%a` instead of `%%a`

```
@for /l %%a in (1,1,25) do @copy test.PRN \\Desktop\Xerox_WorkCentre_5024 & timeout /t 300 /nobreak>nul 2>&1
```

or just setting a variable and counting down to one.

```
@echo off & set timer=25
:timer
if not %timer% equ 0 (
    set /a timer-=1
    copy test.PRN \\Desktop\Xerox_WorkCentre_5024
    timeout /t 300 /nobreak>nul 2>&1
    goto :timer
)
```